# ignore spaces and cases MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
diary_file = tempname();
diary(diary_file);         
myFun(); 
diary('off');             
output = fileread(diary_file);
```

I would like to search a string from `output`, but also to ignore spaces and upper/lower cases. Here is an example for what's in `output`:

---

```
the test  : passed 
number : 4
```

---

```
found = 'thetest:passed'
a = strfind(output,found )
```

How could I ignore spaces and cases from `output`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are not too worried about accidentally matching something like: `'thetEst:passed'` here is what you can do:

Remove all spaces and only compare lower case

```
found = 'With spaces'
found = lower(found(found ~= ' '))
```

This will return

```
found =

withspaces
```

Of course you would also need to do this with each line of output.

Comment: I have to do that on the output log

Comment: found = 'thetest:passed' then when I search in the output , I also need to ignore the spaces from output ...

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
regexpi(output(~isspace(output)), found, 'match')
```

if `output` is a single string, or

```
regexpi(regexprep(output,'\s',''), found, 'match')
```

for the more general case (either `class(output) == 'cell'` *or* `'char'`).

Advantages:

- Fast.
- robust (ALL whitespace (not just spaces) is removed)
- more flexible (you can return starting/ending indices of the match, tokenize, etc.)
- will return original case of the match in output

Disadvantages:

- more typing
- less obvious (more documentation required)
- will return original case of the match in output (yes, there's two sides to that coin)

That last point in both lists is easily forced to lower or uppercase using `lower()` or `upper()`, but if you want same-case, it's a bit more involved:

```
C = regexpi(output(~isspace(output)), found, 'match');
if ~isempty(C)
    C = found; end
```

for single string, or

```
C = regexpi(regexprep(output, '\s', ''), found, 'match')
C(~cellfun('isempty', C)) = {found}
```

for the more general case.

Comment: Of course `regexp` is more flexible, and not really slow. But normally when `strfind` can be used it is faster. Still +1 for robustness against space chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`lower`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) to convert everything to lowercase to solve your case problem. However ignoring whitespace like you want is a little trickier. It looks like you want to keep some spaces but not all, in which case you should split the string by whitespace and compare substrings piecemeal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advertise using regex, e.g. like this:

```
a = regexpi(output, 'the\s*test\s*:\s*passed');
```

If you don't care about the position where the match occurs but only if there's a match at all, removing all whitespaces would be a brute force, and somewhat nasty, possibility:

```
a = strfind(strrrep(output, ' ',''), found);
```

Comment: a = regexpi(output, 'the\s*test\s*:\s*passed') will return a 1x2double ?

Comment: @lola, well, for once, check the docs on regexpi. If I'm not completely mistaken, that means the match occurs twice.

Comment: it returns somting like [1656 2365]

Comment: Just as strfind returns, these are the positions where the matches start. You "translate" this to two e.g. by doing `nMatches = numel(a);`...